# Slow performance of sparse matrix using std::vector

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to implement the functionality of MATLAB function [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).

Insert a value in sparse matrix at a specific index such that:

If a value with same index is already present in the matrix, then the new and old values are added.

Else the new value is appended to the matrix.

The function `addNode` performs correctly but the problem is that it is extremely slow. I call this function in a loop about 100000 times and the program takes more than 3 minutes to run. While MATLAB accomplishes this task in a matter of seconds. Is there any way to optimize the code or use stl algorithms instead of my own function to achieve what I want?

## Code:

```
struct SparseMatNode
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float value;
};

std::vector<SparseMatNode> SparseMatrix;

void addNode(int x, int y, float val)
{
   SparseMatNode n;
   n.x = x;
   n.y = y;
   n.value = val;

   bool alreadyPresent = false;

   int i = 0;
   for(i=0; i<SparseMatrix.size(); i++)
   {
    if((SparseMatrix[i].x == x) && (SparseMatrix[i].y == y))
    {
        alreadyPresent = true;
        break;
    }
   }

   if(alreadyPresent)
   {
    SparseMatrix[i].value += val;
    if(SparseMatrix[i].value == 0.0f)
        SparseMatrix.erase(SparseMatrix.begin + i);
   }
   else
    SparseMatrix.push_back(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thinks that stands out is that you are implementing your own functionality for finding an element: that's what `std::find` is for. So, instead of:

```
bool alreadyPresent = false;

int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<SparseMatrix.size(); i++)
{
  if((SparseMatrix[i].x == x) && (SparseMatrix[i].y == y))
  {
    alreadyPresent = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

You should write:

```
auto it = std::find(SparseMatrix.begin(), SparseMatrix().end(), Comparer);
```

where `Comparer` is a function that compares two `SparseMatNode` objects.

But the main improvement will come from using the appropriate container. Instead of `std::vector`, you will be much better off using an associative container. This way, finding an element will have just a `O(logN)` complexity instead of `O(N)`. You may slighly modify your `SparseMatNode` class as follows:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Coords;
typedef std::pair<const Coords, float> SparseMatNode;
```

You may cover this typedefs inside a class to provide a better interface, of course.

And then:

```
std::unordered_map<Coords, float> SparseMatrix;
```

This way you can use:

```
auto it = SparseMatrix.find(std::make_pair(x, y));
```

to find elements much more efficiently.

Comment: I cant't use `auto`. I'm using VS2008.

Comment: @sgar91 I used `auto` for simplicity, but you can use the right type quite easily (`std::unordered_map<Coords, float>::iterator`). In the same way you can use your available hash map type instead of `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 5):

Sparse matrices aren't typically stored as a vector of triplets as you are attempting.

MATLAB (as well as many other libraries) uses a Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) data structure, which is very efficient for static matrices. The MATLAB function `sparse` also *does not* build the matrix one entry at a time (as you are attempting) - it takes an *array* of triplet entries and packs the whole sequence into a CSC matrix. If you are attempting to build a static sparse matrix this is the way to go.

If you want a dynamic sparse matrix object, that supports efficient insertion and deletion of entries, you could look at different structures - possibly a `std::map` of triplets, or an array of column lists - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) for more information on data formats.

Also, there are many good libraries. If you're wanting to do sparse matrix operations/factorisations etc - [SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/) is a good option, otherwise [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) also has good sparse support.

Comment: this is an old answer, but I still want to know, for large sparse matrix, `Eigen3` would be faster than `stl` `hashmap`?

Answer (score 3):

Sparse matrices are usually stored in compressed sparse row  (CSR) or compressed sparse column (CSC, also called Harwell-Boeing) format. MATLAB by default uses CSC, IIRC, while most sparse matrix packages tend to use CSR.

Anyway, if this is for production usage rather than a learning exercise, I'd recommend using a matrix package with support for sparse matrices. In the C++ world, my favourite is [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried sorting your vector of sparse nodes? Performing a linear search becomes costly every time you add a node. You could Insert In Place and always perform Binary Search.

Comment: All answers are informative, but in the end, your suggestion worked best. Sorting the vector leaded me to forming a better algo for the above mentioned process, and processing time was reduced by magnitudes. :)

Answer (score -1):

Because sparse matrix may be huge and need to be compressed, you may use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). I assume matrix indexes (`x` and `y`) are always positive.

```
#include <unordered_map>

const size_t MAX_X =  1000*1000*1000;
std::unordered_map <size_t, float> matrix;

void addNode (size_t x, size_t y, float val)
{
   size_t index = x + y*MAX_X;
   matrix[index] += val;      //this function can be still faster
   if (matrix[index] == 0)    //using find() / insert() methods
       matrix.erase(index);
}
```

If `std::unordered_map` is not available on your system, you may try `std::tr1::unordered_map` or `stdext::hash_map`...

If you can use more memory, then use `double` instead of `float`, this will improve a bit your processing speed.

Comment: -1: This is just a dense matrix - which is never going to work for general sparse problems (i.e. can easily have 100,000's rows/cols...)

Comment: Hi @DarrenEngwirda I have just finished to write my answer. You did not specified your MIN/MAX for `x` and `y` in your question. I know that my fastest version consumes lots of memory, but please test it, you may have enough memory on your computer.

Comment: For general sparse problems it's not reasonable to use dense representations. It's not just about the memory, it's also the asymptotic performance of algorithms (i.e. sparse matrix multiplication/factorisation etc are much better than the `O(n^3)` performance of dense algorithms...). Also, it's @sgar91's question...

Comment: Ok @DarrenEngwirda, I read what 'sparse' matrix and 'dense' matrix are. Therefore I removed the fastest version as you suggested that was not relevant. I hope my current answer meets the requirements now. Cheers.